# How can I create a result table without decimals in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am trying to calculate the **mean** and **standard deviation** of some data and put the final results in a **table without decimals**. I used the following formula, but I can't get red of the decimals. May be I need to integrate "round" within the "mean" but I don't know how? I would appreciate any help.

```
Mean<-tapply(NKurdish$VOT, NKurdish$Stop, mean)

SD<-tapply(NKurdish$VOT, NKurdish$Stop, sd)

round(Mean, digits = 0)

round(SD, digits = 0)

rbind(Mean,SD)
```

this is what I get

> Mean -116.80000 -130.11667 -116.53333 83.70000 55.06667 66.28333
>
> SD     37.40108   33.26885   28.44588 18.38044 12.21539 17.53166

Comment: `round(Mean, digits = 0)` doesn't change the value of `Mean`, you should `rbind(round(Mean), round(SD))`.

Comment: @lureennaser If your question is resolved, you should click on the check mark that appears next to the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- c(12.11111,12.88888)
as.integer(a) # you probably don't want this
round(a,0) # you probably do want this

# if you want to redefine as integers see...
a2 <- as.integer(round(a,0))
class(a)
class(a2)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This encourages me to ask another question related to choice of integer or numeric. In my paper, I measure voice onset time (VOT), which is a durational property of speech sounds. It includes both negative and positive measurements. I have two questions. First, should I define VOT variable as integer or numeric? Second, if I do an anova  (LMER) to test the effect of some variables on VOT, can I just run it without considering negative and positive numbers?

Comment: That's not an R question. It would be better to ask it in a stats forum like https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry! I am new to all of this.

Comment: No problem...just directing you to a better place.